# SQL Function - conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have the below SQL Server function, however one of the conversions is not working. I get this error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

This is the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_US_UTC_TimeDifference] (
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @date DATETIME
    ,@OneMinuteToMidnightFlag BIT
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(19)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ChangedDate VARCHAR(19)
        ,@StartDate DATETIME
        ,@EndDate DATETIME

    --If this flag is set to 1 then check to see if the time part of the date is 23:59:00
    --in this case we want to do nothing to the timestamp
    IF (@OneMinuteToMidnightFlag = 1)
    BEGIN
        IF (
                DATEPART(hh, @date) = 23
                AND DATEPART(mi, @date) = 59
                )
        BEGIN
            SET @ChangedDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 126)

            RETURN @ChangedDate
        END
    END

    -- Get the EDT start and end dates for the given year
    SET @StartDate = (
            SELECT dbo.fn_EDT_StartDate(Year(@date))
            )
    SET @EndDate = (
            SELECT dbo.fn_EDT_EndDate(Year(@date))
            )

    -- 4 Hour difference between EDT and UTC
    IF (
            @date >= @StartDate
            AND @date < @EndDate
            )
    BEGIN
        SET @ChangedDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEADD(hh, 4, @date), 126)
    END
    -- 5 Hour difference between EST and UTC
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ChangedDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEADD(hh, 5, @date), 126)
    END

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ChangedDate
END
```

Start date function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_EDT_StartDate](@Year INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @March1st DATETIME = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-1900, '1900-03-01')
    DECLARE @DayOfWeek INT = DATEPART(DW, @March1st)
    DECLARE @Result DATETIME

    IF @DayOfWeek = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = DATEADD(D, 7, @March1st)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = DATEADD(D, 15-@DayOfWeek, @March1st)
    END

    RETURN @Result
END
```

End date function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_EDT_EndDate](@Year INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Nov1st DATETIME = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-1900, '1900-11-01')
    DECLARE @DayOfWeek INT = DATEPART(DW, @Nov1st)
    DECLARE @Result DATETIME

    IF @DayOfWeek = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = @Nov1st
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = DATEADD(D, 8-@DayOfWeek, @Nov1st)
    END

    RETURN @Result
END
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
4:36:15,160 [14080] ERROR EMIRAutoTRS.Program - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at EMIRAutoTRS.EMIRDB.PreProcessCalypso() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\EMIRDB.cs:line 104
14:36:15,937 [14080] ERROR EMIRAutoTRS.Program - ProcessEMIRData() failed with error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
14:36:15,937 [14080] ERROR EMIRAutoTRS.Program - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at EMIRAutoTRS.EMIRDB.PreProcessCalypso() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\EMIRDB.cs:line 119
   at EMIRAutoTRS.FileProcessor.ProcessEMIRData() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\FileProcessor.cs:line 913
14:36:15,947 [14080] ERROR EMIRAutoTRS.Program - ProcessFiles() failed with error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
14:36:15,951 [14080] ERROR EMIRAutoTRS.Program - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at EMIRAutoTRS.EMIRDB.PreProcessCalypso() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\EMIRDB.cs:line 119
   at EMIRAutoTRS.FileProcessor.ProcessEMIRData() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\FileProcessor.cs:line 931
   at EMIRAutoTRS.FileProcessor.ProcessFiles() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\FileProcessor.cs:line 259
14:36:15,959 [14080] ERROR EMIRAutoTRS.Program - Error in Main(): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
14:36:15,960 [14080] ERROR EMIRAutoTRS.Program - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at EMIRAutoTRS.EMIRDB.PreProcessCalypso() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\EMIRDB.cs:line 119
   at EMIRAutoTRS.FileProcessor.ProcessEMIRData() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\FileProcessor.cs:line 931
   at EMIRAutoTRS.FileProcessor.ProcessFiles() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\FileProcessor.cs:line 357
   at EMIRAutoTRS.FileProcessor.ProcessEmir() in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\FileProcessor.cs:line 56
   at EMIRAutoTRS.Program.Main(String[] args) in H:\EMIR ASIC TFS Location\EMIRASIC\Development\EMIRAutoTRS\Program.cs:line 70
14:36:15,970 [14080] INFO  EMIRAutoTRS.Program - Exit code was: -1
```

Comment: I guess the error occurs in one of the other two functions you are using.

Comment: where is the code for fn_EDT_StartDate and dbo.fn_EDT_EndDate and what's the point of the function in layman terms? i'm betting you are over complicating this. Also, functions are slow 99% of the time, and nested functions only increase these odds.

Comment: Why would you ever use `nvarchar` for a date? Why don't your [`varchar` and `nvarchar` definitions have lengths](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)?

Comment: Change convert varchar type conversion to 120 instead of 126, it should work

Comment: @scsimon I have added the start date and end date functions in the text box

Comment: That's not the full error you got. It would at least attempt to explain **where** the error occurred. Please quote the entire thing.

Comment: @BHouse I have tried this, it doesn't work

Comment: @underscore_d Added at the bottom, its slightly long

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please add one value for @date parameter you are passing

Answer (score 0):

I executed it in SSMS. It works:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_US_UTC_TimeDifference (GETDATE(), 1) AS Result
UNION ALL SELECT dbo.fn_US_UTC_TimeDifference ('2015-08-23', 1)
UNION ALL SELECT dbo.fn_US_UTC_TimeDifference ('2015-08-23 14:54:12.223', 1);
```

Result

```
2018-01-03T15:04:14
2015-08-23T04:00:00
2015-08-23T18:54:12
```

It looks like you don't pass a datetime as input parameter...